# How do I create a form that displays radio buttons for all on the same page?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am creating a quiz/survey app.

1. How may I use a form (such as a ModelForm) to display the options
   and    a radio button for each question on the same page?  (I have
   read the    docs but seem currently incapable of producing an
   effective    ModelForm.)
2. How may I return all of the radio button selections to    the view by clicking one submit button?

I have spent the day reading the docs, online articles, and as many SO answers as I could find. I suspect that there several factors that I have missed.

I have resorted to writing the page using template tags. I would like to know learn to use a django form properly.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Collection(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Collection of questions'


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    @property
    def options(self):
        options = self.option_set.all()
        return options if options.exists() else 'No options for this question'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Option(models.Model):
    option_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.option_text}'


class Answer(models.Model):
    claim_reference_number = models.IntegerField()
    date_selected = models.DateTimeField('date selected')
    chosen_option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def question(self):
        return self.chosen_option.question

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.claim_reference_number} selected \'{self.chosen_option}\' in response to \'{self.question}\''
```

views.py

```
def new_assessment(request, reference_number):
    collection = Collection.objects.get(pk=1)
    context = {'collection': collection,
               'reference_number': reference_number,
               }
    return render(request, 'ad/templates/new_assessment.html', context)
```

Template

```
<h2>New survey</h2>
<form method="POST" action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div> reference_number = {{ reference_number }}</div>
    {% for question in collection.question_set.all %}
    <h5>{{ question.question_text }}</h5>
        {% for option in question.option_set.all %}
            <p><input type="radio" name="option for {{ question.pk }}" id="option{{ option.pk }}">
            <label for="option{{ option.pk }}">{{ option.option_text }}</label></p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
        <br>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" value="selected">Save</button>
</form>
```

My current results using html and template tags are below. I would like to produce the same thing using a django form.

![Image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Wm6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding:

```
1. How may I use a form (such as a ModelForm) to display the options and a radio button for each question on the same page?
```

I used a model formset factory with a custom model form. This is done by:

a) Creating a custom model form in forms.py ([How to add a custom field in django model form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970096/how-to-add-a-custom-field-in-django-model-form#51970919)). To achieve what I wanted, this involved using the Meta class: to define the `choices` as being in the foreign key of the options related to the particular question; and to add a RadioSelect widget for each option.

b) Creating a model formset. This involves building the model formset with a model formset factory and your custom model form (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

c) Using the view to pass the model formset from forms.py (where I created the modelformset and custom form) to the template.

```
2. How may I return all of the radio button selections to the view by clicking one submit button?
```

Pressing the submit button posts the completed formset back to views. Once it arrives, iterate over the formset data ([Django accessing formset data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362994/django-accessing-formset-data#18363176)). Create and save the appropriate model records in the database.